# What's faster? A Single channel DDR3 or a dual channel DDR2?

Tags: memory, ddr3, ddr2

I wonder if Dual Channel DDR2 is faster than Single Channel DDR3 or that DDR3 is so much faster that the Dual Channel doesn't matter.

Comment: ["The primary benefit of DDR3 SDRAM over its predecessor, DDR2 SDRAM, is the ability to transfer at twice the data rate (8× the speed of its internal memory arrays),"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM)
I'd be interested which is better of 1x4 v 2x2 of the same type, e.g. DDR3.

Comment: Well, unless you can show me a motherboard that supports both and a compelling reason not to choose DDR3, this question is kind of pointless...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DDR3 is much faster, it's been proven (through testing) that dual channel does not offer a particularly large increase in preformance. Especially not enough to out weight the base line performance increase DDR3 has over DDR2. Toms hardware has a pretty nice [breakdown](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/PARALLEL-PROCESSING,1705-11.html) of the modest performance difference between single and dual channel.

Comment: Under those same test conditions, the performance difference between DDR3 and DDR2 would be [even more modest](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2232/7).